# How do I give a method as an attribute argument?

Tags: c#, .net, attributes

I want to apply an attribute which accepts a delegate as an argument, but I can't find the syntax to do it.

For example, to pass a class, you have to use typeof:

```
    [SomeAttribute(typeof(SomeClass))]
```

What is the syntax for a delegate (I am trying to pass a static method)?

```
    [SomeAttribute(??? SomeStaticMethod ???]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is beyond the capacity of the Meta Data.

You could pass the method as a string and also specify the class if you just want to call a static method..

```
[SomeAttribute(typeof(SomeClass), @"SomeStaticMethod")]
```

Naturally you would have to invoke it through reflection, but since you are looking up the custom attributes anyway this probably isn't a big deviation.

Comment: Well, that's too bad. I don't need this in many places, and I don't want to break refactorability. So I'll just place the method inside a class, place an attribute on the method, and target the class.